# Add 'data-text' attribute to TagCloud HTML

Tags: filters, tags

I am trying to add a `data-text` attribute to the selected tag in the TagCloud widget. I want to do this to highlight the selected tag. I have so far managed to add a class to it, but the reason I need to add `data-text` is to copy the tag text into `data-text` so I can set the content in `before` and `after` elements.

Here is what I have :

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', function( $tags_data ) {
    $body_class = get_body_class();
    foreach( $tags_data as $key => $tag ) {
        if( in_array( 'tag-'.$tag['id'], $body_class)) {
            $tags_data[$key]['class'] =  $tags_data[$key]['class'] ." active-tag";
            $tags_data[$key]['data-text'] = $tag['name']; // This doesn't work
        }
    }
    return $tags_data;
});
```

How can I access the tag's HTML to add this `data-text` attribute ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the related [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2651ff3ae805321432bc6d9eac3d62269c937077/wp-includes/category-template.php#L949) in `/wp-includes/category-template.php`, we can see that there is no direct way of adding `data` attributes.

```
/**
 * Filters the data used to generate the tag cloud.
 *
 * @since 4.3.0
 *
 * @param array $tags_data An array of term data for term used to generate the tag cloud.
 */
$tags_data = apply_filters( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', $tags_data );

$a = array();

// Generate the output links array.
foreach ( $tags_data as $key => $tag_data ) {
    $class = $tag_data['class'] . ' tag-link-position-' . ( $key + 1 );
    $a[]   = sprintf(
        '<a href="%1$s"%2$s class="%3$s" style="font-size: %4$s;"%5$s>%6$s%7$s</a>',
        esc_url( $tag_data['url'] ),
        $tag_data['role'],
        esc_attr( $class ),
        esc_attr( str_replace( ',', '.', $tag_data['font_size'] ) . $args['unit'] ),
        $tag_data['aria_label'],
        esc_html( $tag_data['name'] ),
        $tag_data['show_count']
    );
}
```

What we *can* do here is hijack (or maybe stowaway with) the `arial-label` attribute and append our data attribute there:

```
add_filter( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud_data', function( $tags_data ) {
    $body_class = get_body_class();

    foreach( $tags_data as $key => $tag ) {
        if ( in_array( 'tag-' . $tag['id'], $body_class ) ) {
            $tags_data[$key]['class'] = $tags_data[$key]['class'] ." active-tag";
            $tags_data[$key]['aria_label'] .=  ' data-text="' . esc_attr( $tag['name'] ) . '" ';
        }
    }

    return $tags_data;
});
```

For testing, I used this little snippet to add a particular term to the body class, so that it would look like I was on the term archive page for a particular term:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_body_class' );
function wpse_body_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'tag-49';

    return $classes;
}
```

Looking through `/wp-includes/category-template.php` a little further, there is also the 
 `wp_generate_tag_cloud` filter, which would allow us to parse the HTML and modify it to our liking, but that's a bit of a pain, so I went with the aria attribute hack instead.

```
    /**
     * Filters the generated output of a tag cloud.
     *
     * The filter is only evaluated if a true value is passed
     * to the $filter argument in wp_generate_tag_cloud().
     *
     * @since 2.3.0
     *
     * @see wp_generate_tag_cloud()
     *
     * @param array|string $return String containing the generated HTML tag cloud output
     *                             or an array of tag links if the 'format' argument
     *                             equals 'array'.
     * @param WP_Term[]    $tags   An array of terms used in the tag cloud.
     * @param array        $args   An array of wp_generate_tag_cloud() arguments.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_generate_tag_cloud', $return, $tags, $args );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, nice hijack !